# Calc Problem No Solution in my Text

Tags: calculus

Define the function $f$ by $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that f is differentiable at every $x$, including $0$, but that $f'$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

This is what I have so far:

If $f(x)=x^2\sin(x)$, we can use the definition of the derivative to evaluate $f'(0)$.

($f(0+h)-f(0))/h=f(h)/h=h\sin(1/h)$. This approaches $0$ as $h$ approaches $0$; (implying it is differentiable at every $x$ because it is differentiable at $x=0$ and every other $x$).

Now we have to show that $f'$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

$f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ if $x\neq 0$, which has an undefined limit since $\cos(1/x)$ does not approach a particular limit as $x$ approaches $0$. Hence the derivative is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

Almost right. At the end, you need to say that the limit of $2x\sin1/x$ exists; otherwise, you could have some cancellation with $\cos1/x$.